# Acidity of 2-sulfopropanedioic acid in water

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, organosulfur-compounds

Sulfuric acid is a strong acid ($\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ value below that of $\ce{H3O+}$: completely dissociated in water) at its first deprotonation, but is a weak acid ($\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ value over that of $\ce{H3O+}$) in its second one.

Does it also hold for [2-sulfopropanedioic acid](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/54070175) too, being a strong acid at its first deprotonation and being weak acids at its second to fourth deprotonations?

Comment: Probably you get a weak second stage.  Second deprotonation has to come from a carboxyl group -> expected to be a weak acid.

Comment: Yes, the rest of pKa values should be only a bit lower then for malonic acid. There's no 4th value to speak of though.

Comment: I think the 4th deprotonation should be deprotonation from the alpha-carbon.